# Mysql query runing in wamp server mysql console but not through python file or console

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have written this code in python

```
import MySQLdb


mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='tifetal')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql ="select one_number,two_number, one_number * two_number as 'multiplied_number' from multiply_test"
cursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

and my column looks like

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| one_number | two_number | multiplied_number |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 11         | 12         | NULL              |
| 13         | 24         | NULL              |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

if I run it in mysqlconsole it runs perfectly

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| one_number | two_number | multiplied_number |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 11         | 12         |               132 |
| 13         | 24         |               312 |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but while executing python code the multiplied_number column remains nulll .

and I have python version

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and I have windows 10

would be very happy if I could get over this problem.I cannot understand whats happening.
   ok I have got the answer from ikac....Thanks man..plz upvote the answer given by ikac...

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='root',
                       passwd='',
                       db='tifetal')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "update multiply_test set multiplied_number = one_number * two_number"
cursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Comment: I would start by removing the single quotes from `multiplied_number`.  Perhaps that is confusing something.

Comment: tried but no help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run given query in mysql console it shows table that is just a result of your query. That table doesn't exist nor the existing one is updated. Doing `commit` after given query in Python code wont update table either.

What is your intention, to have table updated or just have multiplied columns as a new column in query result?

**Edit 1.**

Okay, so you just want resulting column to work with in Python code, as I understood. Here is how you get it.

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='root',
                       passwd='',
                       db='tifetal')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "select one_number,two_number, one_number * two_number as 'multiplied_number' from multiply_test"
cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    print row

cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

**Edit 2.**

So I understood you wrong. This is how you update table.

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='root',
                       passwd='',
                       db='tifetal')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "update multiply_test set multiplied_number = one_number * two_number"
cursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Comment: multiplied coloumn as a new colomn in query

Comment: I removed "mydb.commit()" but it was of no help.

Comment: it still remained like   
mysql> select * from multiply_test;
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| one_number | two_number | multiplied_number |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 11         | 12         | NULL              |
| 13         | 24         | NULL              |
| 24         | 23         | NULL              |
| 12         | 13         | NULL              |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @Fiore Then you need to run ```r = cursor.fetchall()``` after ```cursor.execute()``` and before ```cursor.close()```. This way you will have results stored in ```r``` as tuples. I'm going to edit the answer with how it should look like.

Comment: C:\Users\supar\Desktop\all>python multiply.py
('11', '12', 132.0)
('13', '24', 312.0)
('24', '23', 552.0)
('12', '13', 156.0)
Done    but it  is a not stored in the database  it is still null

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I have edited it again with new code snippet that should resolve your issue now.